# Scripts missing in Nautilus context menu after update from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: nautilus-script

After updating Ubuntu from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, the scripts entry in Nautilus context (right-click) menu is missing.

I do have a ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/ directory containing scripts. The script where working before the update.

- Any idea?